Word similar to Annualize but regarding day and month
I have daily numbers and I multiply by 365 to annualize the numbers.
I have daily numbers and I multiply by 30 to ______ the numbers.
I have hourly numbers and I multiply by 24 to ______ the numbers.
Are there such verbs?

mensualize would be the corresponding term, but it is not used.  And adjective quotidian could be used in a phrase "by 24 for the quotidian numbers".  But just change your sentences to use for.  "for the annual, monthly, and daily".

I suspect not. Certainly nothing has come to mind as I've thought about this in the last half hour.
I would rewrite the sentences, by using the word calculate and adjectives for the respective time periods:

I have daily numbers and I multiply by 365 to calculate the annual numbers.

I have daily numbers and I multiply by 30 to calculate the monthly numbers.

I have hourly numbers and I multiply by 24 to calculate the daily numbers.


My best guess as to the reason for this difference is the differing etymology of these words. This analysis of the word year suggests Saxon/Germanic/Norse origins. Month and day are similar. On the other hand, annual clearly derives from the Latin word annus, and so relates to other words in that family (annualize, annuity).
